# Python ImportError: cannot import name __version__

Tags: python, python-2.7, oauth

I'm trying to use requests and requests_oauthlib, and right now am just trying the dead simple Twitter verify credentials example they use in the documentation for requests_oauthlib to confirm I've got the basics working. I did a "pip install requests requests_oauthlib" to get the modules. In a terminal window I can "import requests" no problem but when I try "import requests_oauthlib" I get this:

```
>>> import requests_oauthlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests_oauthlib/__init__.py", line 1, in
  <module>
    from .oauth1_auth import OAuth1
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests_oauthlib/oauth1_auth.py", line 10, in  
  <module>
    from requests.utils import to_native_string
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/utils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from . import __version__
ImportError: cannot import name __version__
```

Line 23 of utils.py does indeed look like this:

```
from . import __version__
```

I'm using Python 2.7.5 on Fedora and am currently banging my head against this wall after multiple tries at getting it working, any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Do you have the latest versions of the 2 modules? (Try with `pip install -U`)? I can't reproduce this with a fresh installation.

Comment: Thanks Wooble, before I tried that I rebooted my machine just in case something had gone wonky, and I'm not able to import requests_oauthlib just fine. Sigh... should have tried that earlier. Thanks for the idea though.

Answer (score 7):

Check the `__init__.py` at root dir. openpyxl read these information from .constrants.json file. However, PyInstaller somehow can't make it right. I would you write a `__version__.py` file by yourself and replace them in the `__init__.py`.

Another simpler way is to change `__init__.py` like this:

```
import json
import os


# Modified to make it work in PyInstaller
#try:
#    here = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
#    src_file = os.path.join(here, ".constants.json")
#    with open(src_file) as src:
#        constants = json.load(src)
#        __author__ = constants['__author__']
#        __author_email__ = constants["__author_email__"]
#        __license__ = constants["__license__"]
#        __maintainer_email__ = constants["__maintainer_email__"]
#        __url__ = constants["__url__"]
#        __version__ = constants["__version__"]
#except IOError:
#    # packaged
#    pass

__author__ = 'See AUTHORS'
__author_email__ = 'eric.gazoni@gmail.com'
__license__ = 'MIT/Expat'
__maintainer_email__ = 'openpyxl-users@googlegroups.com'
__url__ = 'http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org'
__version__ = '2.4.0-a1'

"""Imports for the openpyxl package."""
from openpyxl.compat.numbers import NUMPY, PANDAS
from openpyxl.xml import LXML

from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
from openpyxl.reader.excel import load_workbook

print('You are using embedded openpyxl... 2.4.0-a1 ...')
```

Comment: For those who are interested: This is fixed in pyinstaller for the dev branch of pyinstaller 3.3. See [issue on openpyxl](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/498/moving-constants-to-a-configuration-file#comment-34769904) and the [pull request](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/pull/2066) on github.

Answer (score 4):

I used the openpyxl in my project,when I make the exe by py2exe,compile is ok but when I run the compiled exe I met the same problem.

**ImportError: cannot import name __version__**

Try to modify the **init**.py in the root of the openpyxl paceage folder, don't read the **version** from constants.json file,just write like **__version__ = '2.4.1'**.
I solved by this way.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error with the coverage module and none of the above helped.

In the end I deleted my python virtual environment (.venv) and recreated it from my requirements.txt, which solved the problem.