# Error when trying to execute a python script using py2exe

Tags: python, py2exe, cx-freeze, xlrd

I tried many ways to make my code executable and I tried (pypinstaller,py2exe,cx_Freeze) without any results, therefore I focused on py2exe and I solved almost all errors which I faced while using this way, but the last error as I attached below is very difficult to solve it and I wasted a lot of time to solve it and I didn't catch any result, when I tried to run the executable file I got a CMD window with the below error and it disappear quickly, kindly help me to solve it or inform me by a way is supporting (xlrd,openpyxl,selenium,xlsxwriter,pytesser) libraries to I use it to execute my code instead of py2exe,

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
 File "semiFULLTWO.py", line 8, in <module> 
 File "openpyxl\ init .pyc", line 29, in <module> 
 File "openpyxl\workbook\ init .pyc", line 5, in <module> 
 File "openpyxl\workbook\workbook.pyc", line 17, in <module> 
 File "openpyxl\writer\write_only.pyc", line 23, in <module> 
 File "openpyxl\writer\excel.pyc", line 36, in <module> 
 File "openpyxl\packaging\extended.pyc", line 4, in <module> 
ImportError: cannot import name _version_
```

the libraries which I'm using :

```
*# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import time
import xlrd
import base64
import urllib
import requests
import openpyxl
import xlsxwriter
from PIL import Image
from lxml import etree
from io import BytesIO
from pytesser import *
from openpyxl import Workbook
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select*
```

the error related to openpyxl lib :

```
only_date = str ( dt.date ( ) )
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook ( only_date + '.xlsx' )
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet ( )
```

Comment: How do you run your file?

Comment: I open a path of output files "C:\Python27\dist" and double click on it, some times I run it in administrator privilege.

Comment: I would suggest you run it the file from command line. In that way the window would not disappear

Comment: I got the same error message                                                 "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "semiFULLTWO.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "openpyxl\__init__.pyc", line 29, in <module>
  File "openpyxl\workbook\__init__.pyc", line 5, in <module>
  File "openpyxl\workbook\workbook.pyc", line 17, in <module>
  File "openpyxl\writer\write_only.pyc", line 23, in <module>
  File "openpyxl\writer\excel.pyc", line 36, in <module>
  File "openpyxl\packaging\extended.pyc", line 4, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name __version__"

Comment: you should add all your code, not just imports.

Comment: I added the libraries, code is including a private information so it will take almost 2 hours to edit the code to publish it.

Comment: At least show the part where you get the error

Comment: seems that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25121356/python-importerror-cannot-import-name-version) is your issue. Anyway as you can see in the link pyinstaller 3.3 fixed this

Comment: @Vanojx1 I used pyinstaller and it run good but stop at the part of the code without any error.

Comment: Run it in console... check for what in promts. The import error is solved so this question now is irrilevant

Comment: @Vanojx1 why when I use pyinstaller and after running the file I got this error ----> "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ScriptName.py", line 103, in <module>
  File "pytesser.py", line 31, in image_to_string
  File "pytesser.py", line 21, in call_tesseract
  File "subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 640, in _execute_child
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
Failed to execute script ScriptName"